# vertically aligning images to the bottom inside a bootstrap "row"?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, vertical-alignment

In the following example :
http://jsfiddle.net/Fvswp/3/

I have 3 images inside a `row`, i want to align the images to the bottom of the `row`.

I tried other methods like making the outer division position `relative` and that of the image absolute and then `bottom: 0` but it doesn't work since I'm using bootstrap (2.3.1).

I know that there are many other similar questions like mine viz [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14614338/vertical-align-text-image-with-bootstrap)
but none of the solutions work with mine.

How do I vertically align these images to the bottom of the `row`?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want them side by side also?

Comment: yes. I have updated the jsfiddle link, please check http://jsfiddle.net/Fvswp/3/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've updated your jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Fvswp/5/ what you need to do is add a css property `display: block;` to your `img` element like so

**CSS**

```
img { display: block;}
```

This will remove that bottom space, its kind of a default line of code you should use in all your projects that fix's this issue.

*PS: Thanks for posting a fiddle*

Comment: thanks @Mitchell, but i tried Increasing the height of one of the images, and it didnt work, check this out http://jsfiddle.net/Fvswp/7/

Comment: That's because your other images are smaller then your first one, your row height is based off of the height of the biggest element inside of it which is your first image so that's the height of the row, now to get them all on the bottom you can just apply position absolute to the generic class and set its property to `bottom: 0;`.

Comment: Can you add a couple more images to your js fiddle like one small and one big, thank!

Comment: There is a couple ways to do that but because your images already have `ids` we can set the header `position` to `relative` and then position the `img` ids `absolute` where you need them, check out the fiddle I updated http://jsfiddle.net/Fvswp/10/

Comment: Awesome, no worries! PS: I would suggest using a better framework like foundation that sets all its columns to relative so you can easily `postion` something `absolute` inside of any column, just a thought though.

Answer (score -1):

Make columns equal height (equal to the height of the largest image) and position images inside columns at the bottom:

```
#header > div {
    height: 128px;
    position: relative;
}
#header > div > img {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Fvswp/6/